# Css import not working on MVC 4

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-4

I have this Ajax form

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", OnSuccess = "SucessoCriarUsuario", OnFailure = "FalhaCriarUsuario" }))
{

    <div class="separador">
        <div class="linha1">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Nome)
            <br />
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Nome)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Nome)
        </div>
        <div class="linha1">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Login)
            <br />
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Login)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Login)
        </div>
        <div class="linha2">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email)
            <br />
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email)
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <br />
    <div class="separador">
        <div class="linha2">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Perfil)<br>
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Perfil, new SelectList(UsuarioController.ObterListaPerfis(User.Identity.Name)))
        </div>
        <div class="linha2">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Ativacao)<br>
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Ativacao, new SelectList(new List<string> { "Ativo", "Inativo" }))
        </div>
        <div class="linha2">
            <br>
            <input type="submit" value="Salvar" />
            <input type="button" id="btnCancelar" value="Cancelar" />
        </div>
    </div>

}
```

And I have the override css for the validationmessagefor field and textBoxFor field... But when I import the css file that has these override classes...

```
<head>
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/ModalStyle.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
```

The CSS doesn't work on the validationmessageFor and textBoxFor... It only works when I put the css ON the same page

```
<head>
<style type="text/css">

.input-validation-error
{
    border: 1px solid red;
}


.field-validation-error
{
    color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
}

</style>
</head>
```

Like This it worked.... why is that?
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Is the browser able to find the file?  You can tell this using browser debugging.  What does the ModalStyle.css look like?

Comment: It finds it, the other classes on the css make effect on the div with the same class, only the validationmessageFor and textBoxfor that dont get the classes

Comment: Are the original class definitions for `.input-validation-error` and `.field-validation-error` loaded and still in effect?

Answer (score 0):

Its probably being overridden by another css or css rule. Change it (CSS Rules) to the following in the css file and see if it fixes it:

```
.input-validation-error
{
    border: 1px solid red !important;
}


.field-validation-error
{
    color: red !important;
    font-weight: bold !important;
}
```